# How to get newly defined variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, global-variables

I was trying to come up with a way to isolate variables that have been defined **after** a certain point in my code. For this task, I wrote the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy

beginning = deepcopy(dict(globals()))  # getting the current stand
a = 5  # new variable gets defined
# possibly more code with other definitions here
end = {k: v for k, v in dict(globals()).items() if k not in beginning}
```

Upon printing `end` I was expecting to see `{'a': 5}` **only**, but that was not the case. Instead, I got the entire scope all over again.

As a result, it is clear that the `if` condition on the dictionary comprehension fails. So I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can my desired result be achieved?

**P.S:** I am using Python 3.6.1

Comment: Running your code verbatim in python3.5 gives me this `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'` from the line where the deepcopy happens.

Comment: @shuttle87 [Take a look](https://repl.it/repls/MundaneAverageKakapo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get `TypeError: can't pickle module objects` when applying `deepcopy()` but ignoring that (and doing a shallow copy), you can get your desired output.

I think your conceptual mistake was to forget that `beginning` has also been added to the `globals()` `dict` and needs to be excluded in the `if` clause:

```
>>> beginning = dict(globals())
>>> a = 5
>>> end = {k: v for k, v in dict(globals()).items() if k not in beginning and k != 'beginning'}
>>> end
{'a': 5}
```